# How to run beforeValidate only for update action in Sails framework?

Tags: sails.js

I want to know current action when trigger beforeValidate in Sails framework, please review my code:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        ...
        log: 'string'
    },
    beforeValidate: function(values, cb) {

        // I want to know the action is create new record or update current record
        // If action is update, how to get primary key of record will be updated

        /*
        if (isCreateNewRecord) {
            values.log = 'New created...'; // for example
        } else {
            values.log = 'Update record ID: ' + recordID;
        }
        */

        cb();
    }
}
```

Thanks so much for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're not supposed to do that... And this is why we have `beforeCreate` and `beforeUpdate`!

```js
beforeCreate: function (values, cb) {
  values.log = 'New created...';

  return cb();
},

beforeUpdate: function (valuesToUpdate, cb) {
  valuesToUpdate.log = 'Update record ID: ' + valuesToUpdate.id;

  return cb();
}
```

Check out [the docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks).

Comment: I check the docs, also when use beforeUpdate, can we get recordID (the primary key of record will be updated)?

Comment: Oops, I forgot this question, I've edited my answer and add the record id as you need it

Comment: beforeUpdate valuesToUpdate.id === undefined, but afterUpdate can get valuesToUpdate.id. I still want to get primary key for update in beforeValidate for other issues, I also think it not supposed to do that. Thanks.

Comment: `valuesToUpdate.id` should exist at this point. Have you overriden your primary key?

Comment: sails blueprint, so to update I post to url /model/:id, then I log valuesToUpdate.id, it show undefined

Comment: There is no blueprint route for `POST /model/:id` [to my knowledge](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api). What if you do a `PUT` request to the same route?

Comment: yes, I sorry, I want to said PUT /model/:id to update, then I log valuesToUpdate.id, it show undefined

Comment: I found this, when I PUT /model/:id with data.id = null, valuesToUpdate.id will show undefined, but when data.id = primary key value, it will show correct valuesToUpdate.id in beforeUpdate and beforeValidate, thanks so much for your time Yann Bertrand